# HTML code into Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, firebase-realtime-database

I am modifying this [codepen code](http://codepen.io/kharrop/pen/YWvpRo) because I want to populate the UI with Firebase data.

Inside HTML body

```
<div class="container positions">
<h2>Job Openings</h2>
<ul>
<li class="pos-card" id="pos_1">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="return">Return to listings   </div>
<div class="container refer-card" id="jobapp">
</div>



  <script>
  var jobTitle = document.getElementById('jobTitle');
  var jobDescription= document.getElementById('jobDescription');

   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
        database = firebase.database();

       var ref = database.ref('/Jobs/');
    ref.on('value', gotData,  errData);

  }
  })

   function gotData(data) { 

  var jobs = data.val();
  var keys = Object.keys(jobs);

  var container = document.getElementById('pos_1'); 

for (var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++) {
var k = keys[i];
var newCard = `

<li class="pos-card" id="pos_1">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="title new">UI/UX Designer</div>
        <div class="dept">Design</div>
        <div class="date">June 4</div>
        <div class="refer">Refer</div>
      </div>
      <ul class="desc">
        <li>6+ years’ experience designing desktop and mobile apps.</li>
        <li>Deep appreciation for simple solutions to complex problems.</li>
        <li>An amazing portfolio demonstrating successful delivery of innovative design solutions.</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
      <div class="return">Return to listings   </div>
  <div class="container refer-card">
  <div class="modal confirmed"><span class="close-modal"></span>
  <h2>Thank you!</h2>
 <p><span id="refer_name" class="focus"></span> has been submitted for the <span id="refer_pos" class="focus"></span> position.</p>
</div>
<div class="sign-up card">
 <div class="card__header"> 
  <h1>Employee Referral</h1>
  <div class="description">For more information, please consult the   <a href="#">employee handbook</a>.</div>
 </div>
 <div class="card__content">
  <form class="referral" method="post">
    <div class="field line">
      <input class="req" maxlength="240" type="text" name="name" value="" required="required" id="name"/>
      <label class="placeholder" for="name">Full Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field line">
      <input class="req" maxlength="240" type="email" name="email" value="" required="required" id="email"/>
      <label class="placeholder" for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field line inline">
      <input class="req" maxlength="240" type="text" name="position" value="" required="required" id="position"/>
      <label class="placeholder" for="position">Position</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field inline right"><span class="dropdown-wrapper">
        <select class="empty" name="department" id="choice">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Department</option>
          <option value="1">Development</option>
          <option value="2">Sales</option>
          <option value="3">QA</option>
          <option value="4">Design</option>
          <option value="5">HR</option>
          <option value="6">Research  </option>
        </select></span></div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled"  id="btn"/>
    </div><a class="reset" href="#">Reset </a>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>

`;
container.innerHTML += newCard;

}
}

</script>
```

The modified code produced the image below:

[image]

but the when the refer tab is clicked nothing happens as compared to the original code that fades in the "refer card". Please for better clarity check out the codepen link. When the refer tab is clicked on the original code the refer card fades in. I can't get my code to do that and I am using the same CSS and JS file. How can I execute the same behavior in my loop function?

Comment: Just to be sure, I don't see any `<script>` tags.

Comment: the script tags have been added. they were mistakenly ommitted @Rob

Answer (score 0):

You are dynamically generating those elements so any listener applied on page load wont be available.
Update your click handler to:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.refer', function(e){
    //...
}
```

Comment: I updated my click handler to                                            $('.container').on('click', '.refer', function(e){
     $('.positions').addClass('fadeOut');
   $('.refer-card').addClass('fade');
   $('.return').fadeIn('fast');
})     the refer tab is clicked the "post-card" fade out but the .refer-card does not fade in